# SCROLLINFO PInvoke from WinForms C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, scrollbar, pinvoke

I am writing a control with scrollbars, and I want it to behave (in terms of it's scrollbars) like a `RichTextBox`; i.e. when the bars are "Forced", I want them to be disabled until they become necessary. I have this working (kind of) but I do not see the results in the Windows Forms Designer until I build the project.

**Code:**

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public class ScrollControl : Control
    {
        public const int WS_HSCROLL = 0x00100000;
        public const int WS_VSCROLL = 0x00200000;

        private RichTextBoxScrollBars sb;

        public RichTextBoxScrollBars ScrollBars
        {
            get
            {
                return this.sb;
            }

            set
            {
                this.sb = value;
                this.UpdateScrollBars();
            }
        }

        protected override CreateParams CreateParams
        {
            get
            {
                CreateParams result = base.CreateParams;
                result.Style |= WS_HSCROLL;
                result.Style |= WS_VSCROLL;
                return result;
            }
        }

        private void UpdateScrollBars()
        {
            ScrollOrientation dirH = ScrollOrientation.HorizontalScroll;
            ScrollInfoMask maskH = ScrollInfoMask.SIF_ALL;

            ScrollOrientation dirV = ScrollOrientation.VerticalScroll;
            ScrollInfoMask maskV = ScrollInfoMask.SIF_ALL;

            if (this.ScrollBars == RichTextBoxScrollBars.ForcedVertical || this.ScrollBars == RichTextBoxScrollBars.ForcedBoth)
            {
                maskV |= ScrollInfoMask.SIF_DISABLENOSCROLL;
            }

            if(this.ScrollBars == RichTextBoxScrollBars.ForcedHorizontal || this.ScrollBars == RichTextBoxScrollBars.ForcedBoth)
            {
                maskH |= ScrollInfoMask.SIF_DISABLENOSCROLL;
            }

            SCROLLINFO sV = new SCROLLINFO();
            SCROLLINFO sH = new SCROLLINFO();

            sV.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf<SCROLLINFO>();
            sH.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf<SCROLLINFO>();

            sV.fMask = (uint)maskV;
            sH.fMask = (uint)maskH;

            SetScrollInfo(this.Handle, (int)dirV, ref sV, true);
            SetScrollInfo(this.Handle, (int)dirH, ref sH, true);
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern int SetScrollInfo(IntPtr hwnd, int fnBar, [In] ref SCROLLINFO lpsi, bool fRedraw);
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct SCROLLINFO
    {
        public uint cbSize;
        public uint fMask;
        public int nMin;
        public int nMax;
        public uint nPage;
        public int nPos;
        public int nTrackPos;
    }

    public enum ScrollInfoMask
    {
        SIF_RANGE = 0x0001,
        SIF_PAGE = 0x0002,
        SIF_POS = 0x0004,
        SIF_DISABLENOSCROLL = 0x0008,
        SIF_TRACKPOS = 0x0010,
        SIF_ALL = SIF_RANGE | SIF_PAGE | SIF_POS | SIF_TRACKPOS
    }
}
```

Here, I have built the control and loaded it into a form (16x padding on the form to clearly display the bounds of the control)

[image: Image 1]

Here, I have set the ScrollBars property to ForcedVertical, but this **does not** display until I build the solution

[image: Image 2]

Here I have selected ForcedBoth, again, this **only displays** after a build

[image: Image 3]

**Question:**

How do I get the Designer to update immediately, so that I can see my changes without requiring constant builds?

**Note:**

Please excuse the poor code quality (mutable structs, horrid names etc) - this is only a demonstration!

I also don't want to use `ScrollableControl`...it sucks! I need **COMPLETE** control over the ScrollBars - the way Win32 intended!

`.Invalidate()` `.Update()` and `.Refresh()` don't work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to recreate the window to do that.  Try it this way:

```
public RichTextBoxScrollBars ScrollBars {
  get {
    return this.sb;
  }
  set {
    this.sb = value;
    this.RecreateHandle();
  }
}

protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e) {
  base.OnHandleCreated(e);
  UpdateScrollBars();
}
```

Comment: OMG...GENIUS! YOU SIR, DESERVE A MEDAL!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you need to force your control to be redrawn, i.e., at the end of your `UpdateScrollBars` method, add `Invalidate();`.

EDIT: The following works for me (at the end of `UpdateScrollBars`):

```
Invalidate();
Update();
```

Comment: Nope, tried that...also tried using this in conjuction with Update() and Refresh()...nothing works.

Comment: @series0ne: You did not write that in your original post. Downvoting does not seem fair considering that.

Comment: Fair comment, apologies

Comment: I found a solution which works for me (VS 2013). I edited my answer. Please let me know whether this works for you too.

Comment: Nope :-( Refresh(); is AFAIK the same as .Invalidate(); .Update(); - I think this goes a little deeper than just repainting the form, hence Invalidate, Update and Refresh don't work.